# Three.js: Raycast Has an Empty Array of Intersects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using this example for my WebGL panorama cube: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=pano#webgl_panorama_equirectangular

I want to know what cube user clicks on and I discovered I can use Raycaster for this. According to docs I added the following function:

```
    function onMouseDown( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3(
            ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
          - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
            1 );

        //projector.unprojectVector( mouseVector, camera );
        mouseVector.unproject( camera );
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, mouseVector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

        // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
        console.log(intersects);
        if (intersects.length>0){
            console.log("Intersected object:", intersects.length);
            intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
        }
        // ...
```

But `intersects` is always empty. My scene is defined as

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

and has skyBox added:

```
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ), materials );
skyBox.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1, 1, - 1 ) );
scene.add( skyBox );
```

I've seen similar posts related to this issue but could not figure out how to apply to this example. Any directions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your material definition:

```
var materials = new THREE.SomeMaterial({
    /* other settings */,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
```

`Raycaster` won't intersect back-faces unless the `side` property is set to `THREE.BackSide` or `THREE.DoubleSide`. Even though your scaling technically inverts the face direction, the vertex order stays the same, which is what's important to `Raycaster`.

**Some further explanation**

The snippet below is showing how a ray projected from a camera at the center of a skybox inverted by a -Z scale might look.

The box itself looks weird because it has been -Z scaled, and the normals no longer match the material. But that's here nor there.

The green arrow represents the original ray. The red arrow represents what will happen to that ray inside the `Mesh.raycast` function, which will apply the inverse of the object's world matrix to the ray, but not to the object's geometry. This is a whole different problem.

The point I'm making is that within `Mesh.raycast`, it does not affect the vertex/index order, so when it checks the triangles of the mesh, they are still in their original order. For a standard `BoxGeometry`/`BoxBufferGeometry`, this means the faces all face outward from the geometric origin.

This means the rays (regardless of how the transformation matrix affects them) are still trying to intersect the back-face of those triangles, which will not work unless the material is set to `THREE.DoubleSide`. (It can also be set to `THREE.BackSide`, but the -Z scale will ruin that.)

Clicking either of the raycast buttons will produce 0 intersects if the -Z scaled box is not set to `THREE.DoubleSide` (default). Click the "Set THREE.DoubleSide" button and try it again--it will now intersect.

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, stats;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
 FOV = 35,
 NEAR = 1,
 FAR = 1000,
  ray1, ray2, mesh;

function populateScene(){
 var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10),
  cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: "red", transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
  mesh.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1, 1, -1 ) );
  mesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);
 scene.add(mesh);
  
  var dir = new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 1);
  dir.normalize();
  ray1 = new THREE.Ray(new THREE.Vector3(), dir);
  
  var arrow1 = new THREE.ArrowHelper(ray1.direction, ray1.origin, 20, 0x00ff00);
  scene.add(arrow1);
  
  var inverseMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  inverseMatrix.getInverse(mesh.matrixWorld);
  
  ray2 = ray1.clone();
  ray2.applyMatrix4(inverseMatrix);
  
  var arrow2 = new THREE.ArrowHelper(ray2.direction, ray2.origin, 20, 0xff0000);
  scene.add(arrow2);
}

function init() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "slateGray";

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
 document.body.style.margin = "0";
 document.body.style.padding = "0";

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
 camera.position.z = 50;
 scene.add(camera);

 controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
 controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;
 controls.rotateSpeed = 3;

 var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
 camera.add(light);

 stats = new Stats();
 stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
 stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
 document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);

 resize();
 window.onresize = resize;

 populateScene();

 animate();
  
  var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  document.getElementById("greenCast").addEventListener("click", function(){
    rayCaster.ray.copy(ray1);
    alert(rayCaster.intersectObject(mesh).length + " intersections!");
  });
  document.getElementById("redCast").addEventListener("click", function(){
    rayCaster.ray.copy(ray2);
    alert(rayCaster.intersectObject(mesh).length + " intersections!");
  });
  document.getElementById("setSide").addEventListener("click", function(){
    mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
  });
}

function resize() {
 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 if (renderer && camera && controls) {
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  controls.handleResize();
 }
}

function render() {
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 render();
 controls.update();
 stats.update();
}

function threeReady() {
 init();
}

(function () {
 function addScript(url, callback) {
  callback = callback || function () { };
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.addEventListener("load", callback);
  script.setAttribute("src", url);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
 }

 addScript("https://threejs.org/build/three.js", function () {
  addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js", function () {
   addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js", function () {
    threeReady();
   })
  })
 })
})();
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input id="greenCast" type="button" value="Cast Green">
<input id="redCast" type="button" value="Cast Red">
<input id="setSide" type="button" value="Set THREE.DoubleSide">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might actually want to use an easier process to determine your ray from the camera:

```
THREE.Raycaster.prototype.setFromCamera( Vector2, Camera );
```

Simply define your mouse coordinates as you do in a `Vector2`, then pass the elements to the Raycaster and let it do its thing. It hides the complexity of intersecting the frustrum with the ray from the camera, and should solve your problem.

(Also, the raycaster does indeed only intersect faces that face the ray directly, but since your SkyBox has been inverted its geometries faces are pointing to the inside of the box, so they should intersect if the camera is inside the box. Another possibility is that your box is further away than the raycasters default `far` value.)

```js
function onMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var mouseVector = new THREE.Vector2(
         event.clientX / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1,
        -event.clientY / window.innerHeight * 2 + 1
    );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouseVector, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
        
    console.log(intersects);
        
    if( intersects.length > 0 ){

        console.log( "Intersected object:", intersects[ 0 ] );
        intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

    }

}
```

Comment: FWIW, `Raycaster.far` defaults to `Infinity`, so no problems there. :)

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere, your answer also helped me understand

Answer (score 0):

When using the `raycaster.intersectObjects()` method in `Three.js`, it's crucial to provide the targeted objects in the form of an array argument. Previously, the usage was `const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(planeMesh);`. However, to ensure proper functionality and avoid returning an empty array, it's essential to encapsulate the target object or objects within an additional set of square brackets, like this: `const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([planeMesh]);`. This adjustment, enclosing the object reference within an array, allows the raycaster to correctly identify intersections and prevents an empty intersection array from being returned.

[image: image link]